# Import Image Issue

Tags: java

I am having issues importing and drawing a simple Image on java.
Here is my code.

```
public class JGAME
{
static JFrame window = new JFrame("Gun Them Down");
static BufferedImage myImage;
static JPanel background = new JPanel();

private static void CreateMenuWindow()
{
    window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    window.setSize(600, 600);
    window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    window.setResizable(false);
    window.setVisible(true);
    window.add(background);

}

public static void paint(Graphics g)
{
    g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{   
   try
        {
            myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/Pacman.png"));
            //myImage = ImageIO.read(JGAME.class.getResource("resources/dexter.jpeg"));
        }catch(IOException ex)
        {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }

   CreateMenuWindow();
}
}
```

Java finds the file("src/resources/Pacman.png") but doesnt paint my Image.

Thanks,
Steve

Comment: Where is your file located? Can we see structure of your project? How are you running it (is it maybe jar)?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post your OS and the IDE you are using. With my experience, IDE in mac and Windows work slightly differently in different OS.

Comment: @user3437460 When searching for resources, it makes no difference what os you're using

Comment: To reiterate, where is the image located in context to your source files and binaries?

Comment: The file is located in D:\.....\JGAME\src\resources\dexter.jpeg

Comment: here is a photo to see better http://it.tinypic.com/r/33a47b8/8

Comment: and yes it is jar @Pshemo

Comment: "*I don't get why java doesn't find my File*" how do you know it doesn't find your file? "it always returns "null"*" where is your code which uses `myImage` (`paint` and `loadImage` methods are never invoked in your example)? Is it possible that `myImage` stays null (because it is default value of empty field) because you actually never run code which initialized it?

Comment: @Pshemo i modified my script placing the instructions in loadImage() inside main method and i am starting to think it may have found the file the problem is on the paint method... thats what i am starting to think about

Comment: Can you show us your changes? Maybe [edit] your question so we would see how you actually using these methods.

Comment: Where do you expect `paint` method to be executed and why you expect it there?

Comment: i tried adding Graphics g1 and executing paint(g1) in main method but i'm not very sure it is what i should do... i can't remember how to instantiate it.

Comment: @Pshemo what if i extend Canvas class would it resolve anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finaly found a way to load my image i will post the code down here.

```
public class JGAME
{
    static JFrame window = new JFrame("Gun Them Down");
    static BufferedImage myImage;

    private static void CreateMenuWindow()
    {
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setSize(600, 600);
        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {   
        myImage = ImageIO.read(new File("D:\\STEFANO\\Progetti Java\\JGAME\\src\\resources\\Pacman.png"));

        JPanel background = new JPanel()
        {
            @Override
            protected void paintComponent(Graphics g)
            {
                super.paintComponent(g);
                g.drawImage(myImage, 0, 0, null);
            }
        };

       window.add(background);
       CreateMenuWindow();
    }
}
```

I used the `paintComponent()` method to paint directly on my Panel and it worked!

Comment: Don't use `ImageIO.read(new File(path))` because `path` will be not related to jar. If you are planning to distribute your app as jar you should place your resources inside it and use `ImageIO.read(JGAME.class.getResource("/resources/Pacman.png"));` to access them (`/` will be treated as main directory containing classes in Jar).

Comment: BTW good job with discovering `paintComponent` method and not forgetting about adding `super.paintComponent(g);` at its start, to let standard Swing logic be also executed while repainting component.

Comment: they work both ImageIO.read(new File(path)) and ImageIO.read(JGAME.class.getResource(path)) <---i prefer this one that i used in the first place as you can see in my first code i commented it. But thank you for your assistance and your Knowledge Phsemo really appreciated.

Comment: "*How can i give you rep points?*" you don't have to, I didn't really do much, you found solution on your own :)

Comment: ok Pshermo! hope this question helps someone that had my same problem. I will accept my answer tomorrow :)

Answer (score 1):

JGAME.class.getResource("/resources/dexter.jpeg")

getResource takes a String of name of the resource you are looking for and returns its url. The rule of searching the resource is defined by ClassLoader. 
Paraphrased from: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)

So if you know the url of the file, I suggest that you simply do ImageIO.read("resources/dexter.jpeg");
Assuming resources folder is under the project directory.

Sorry for the confusion earlier, I misread your code.

Comment: *"I think when you start the file location with "/" it starts in the root of your file system"* - No, but I do believe that using .class changes the context of how the class loader searches for the resources, removing the need for the leading "/"

Comment: @MadProgrammer but doesn't an absolute path start with / and a relative path does not need the / ? It will just go from the project directory? Or is it just true for Eclipse?

Comment: Yes, but the context, in this case, is the classpath not the file system

Comment: I "think" you're on the right track, just mis-stated a small fact ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try move the resources folder to JGAME and 
ImageIO.read("resources/dexter.jpeg");

or

ImageIO.read("src/resources/dexter.jpeg");

Comment: Nothing changed my friend still can't find my Image

Comment: Did you double check that the full file name is dexter.jpeg not maybe dexter.jpg ?

Comment: Also, how do you call loadImage()? it seems not being called anywhere.. and maybe try the full url in ImageIO.read("D:\\.....\\JGAME\\src\\resources\\dexter.jpeg"); with double slashes and full path?

Comment: ok i edited my code placing all the instructions in the loadImage() method in my main method, and i insert the full url but still nothing changes.. so strange..

Comment: what do you think about my paint() method? maybe it is wrong

Comment: Ahhh...Try this: ImageIO.read(new File("src/resources/dexter.jpeg"));

Comment: The paint() method seems right, but when I try it, I can't create a Graphics object...am I missing something?

Comment: Looks like your class needs to extend Component class. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/ and http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/examples/LoadImageApp.java

Answer (score 0):

I assume that your image is placed under src/main/resources

So, you can access the file the following way:

```
 myImage = ImageIO.read(JGAME.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("dexter.jpg"));
```

Answer (score 0):

From what it looks like you're trying to do, and assuming you're on Windows:

`ImageIO.read(getCodeBase() + "\\resources\\dexter.jpeg");`

`getCodeBase()` returns the path of the .java file.

In windows, files aren't separated by "/" they are separated by "\".
Because "\" is the escape sequence for `char`s, you have to put two, and java recognizes it as one.

Comment: The path separator is relievent, in windows, Java will convert the "/" to "\" automatically. When using it for searching for resources, I've never really used "\" so I'm no even sure it will work or not